# Roslyn doubts on SyntaxTree construction

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

### Disclaimer

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, but even after reading official documentation I  don't clearly understand how Roslyn create a syntax tree.

### Example

Consider the following, simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace aopsample
{
    
    class UsbReadWriter
    {
       
        public bool ReadFromUsb()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public virtual bool WriteToUsb()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I get a `SyntaxTree` for this code and make something like this, very rough and simple, but I just need to understand.

```
  string[]lines =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);      
  string tocompile = string.Join(string.Empty, lines);  

  SyntaxNode root = tree.GetRoot(new CancellationToken());
  foreach (SyntaxNode sn in root.ChildNodes())
  {
      if (sn.Kind == SyntaxKind.NamespaceDeclaration)
      {
         //I get a namespace, so it's Child node just will be class
         foreach (SyntaxNode sname in sn.ChildNodes())
         {
             if (sname.Kind == SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration)
             {
                 //I get class, so it's  Children will be methods of the class        
                 foreach (SyntaxNode sclass in sname.ChildNodes()) // **{1}** 
                 {
                     if (sclass.Kind == SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration) 
                     {
                        
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
```

And it works pretty well.

### Trouble

But, it's enough to add a comment to the  `ReadFromUsb()` method, something like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads a data from Usb
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool ReadFromUsb()
{
    return true;
}
```

And `ChildNodes()` call on {1} marked line, for **CLASS** (???) returns 0.

### Question

Why adding a comment to member function, resets the collection of parent CLASS children Syntax nodes ?

What am I missing ?

Comment: As a side note, I think using LINQ would make zour code much clearer. And I think this applies generaly to selecting nodes in Roslyn.

Comment: @svick: yes, ok. As I mantioned this code is just "fast and dirty".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following a chat discussion, we determined that the problem was the the code to parse was being constructed with:

```
string[]lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename); 
string tocompile = string.Join(string.Empty, lines);
```

Which puts all of the code onto a single line.  Therefore everything after `//` becomes a comment.  The solution is just to use `Environment.NewLine` as the join character, or use `ReadAllText` instead of `ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 3):

Since comments can appear anywhere at all in source code, they are not modeled as a `ChildNode`, which are reserved for true syntactic elements. Instead, they are considered `SyntaxTrivia`.  In your example, you should be able to look at the `LeadingTrivia` of the method and see the comment.

Additionally, since this is an XML doc comment which may have interesting structure of it's own, that will be modeled as it's own little tree that you can get with the `GetStructure()` method of the `SyntaxTrivia`.

Comment: Ok, but the question is not: how can I find the comments among childs, but why adding the new comment affects (apparently) the syntax tree structure. In fact, considering, that `comments` like, for example `empty spaces`, `preprocessor dirrectives` make not part of syntax tree strucutre, why should add/remove of them affect in *any* way childrens of the *parent* SyntaxNode ?

Comment: Every edit you make to a file makes it into a different tree.  In Roslyn `SyntaxTree` and `SyntaxNode` objects are immutable and fully representational.  Once constructed they _never_ change, and they model every bit of text in the file.  That means that if you make a change to the code, you will get a different tree back every time, because it's `ChildNodes` will have different values for their `Span` properties.

Comment: Note that if you are editing in Visual Studio, we use an incremental parsing strategy such that we actually share most of the internal storage of the tree between parses, it's only a thin layer of wrapper objects that are created on access that are actually new each time.  The whitepaper does a good job explaining the "re-spining" process that we use here.

Comment: But I rebuild it every time, naturally. When I change a source file, I stop and rebuild my program, so, in my understanding, I reconstruct a SyntaxTree from a "new" file.

Comment: How are you adding the comment?  Are you doing it programmatically?  If so, and you're using something like `SyntaxNode.Replace`, you'll need to keep the return value and look in it's tree to see the changed nodes.

Comment: no no Kevin, I just 1. Stop VS 2. Add comment by hand 3. Rebuild the program. It's actually so easy, that I surprised by myself, why it chnage it's behaviour. Or, as I said, I'm missing something *really* obviouse.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6269/discussion-between-kevin-pilch-bisson-and-tigran)

Answer (score 1):

For such situations, Using `CSharpSyntaxWalker` can be of great help.

Following is sample extracted from [Josh Varty's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300908/joshvarty) blog [here](https://joshvarty.com/2014/07/26/learn-roslyn-now-part-4-csharpsyntaxwalker/) which helps to print syntax tree on console :

```
 public class CustomWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    static int Tabs = 0;
    public override void Visit(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        Tabs++;
        var indents = new String('\t', Tabs);
        Console.WriteLine(indents + node.Kind());
        base.Visit(node);
        Tabs--;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
        public class MyClass
        {
            public void MyMethod()
            {
            }
            public void MyMethod(int n)
            {
            }
       ");

    var walker = new CustomWalker();
    walker.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
}
```

You can also print trivias by calling `GetLeadingTrivia` and `GetTrailingTrivia` methods on syntax nodes.